# Do we have Mobile SDK for Google Cloud Vision to Detect explicit content (SafeSearch)?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, google-cloud-vision, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to Detect explicit content (SafeSearch) for a local image in my both android and ios apps but was not able to find enough documentation about the sdks. Does Cloud Vision have mobile sdk for performing explicit content (SafeSearch)? If not, What is the fastest way to check for image moderation from the device?
Does Firebase-Mlkit offer this functionality?

Tried looking at these documentation but I didn't find them very clear. Also it appears there are many old examples on this topic.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search#vision_safe_search_detection-drest
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search

Answer (score 0):

Firebase-MLKit does not offer this functionality, but you can follow the documentations linked in your question to integrate with Google Cloud Vision API directly.